# is there any workaround to put stored properties into extensions in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, extension-methods

I'm creating my project all in code and it was a bit confusing and difficult to read because there were several lines just to set up UIElements in my code...

so I tried to insert this bulky part into an extension and got an error saying that stored properties can't go into extensions, after that my solution was as follows...

```
weak var centraliseButton: UIButton!
weak var infoButton: UIButton!
weak var seeFireButton: UIButton!
weak var locatManager: CLLocationManager!
weak var mapkitView: MKMapView!
weak var containerViewForInfoButton: UIView!
weak var containerViewForSeeFireButton: UIView!
```

and then I set up evertyhing in an function in a extension file and call this function inside `viewDidLoad()`, but again I got tons of runtime errors and nils because I access self inside some of these properties and they were `lazy var` before, so my last solution was the following:

```
lazy var centraliseButton: UIButton = UIButton()
lazy var infoButton: UIButton = UIButton()
lazy var seeFireButton: UIButton = UIButton()
lazy var locatManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
lazy var mapkitView: MKMapView = MKMapView()
lazy var containerViewForInfoButton: UIView = UIView()
lazy var containerViewForSeeFireButton: UIView = UIView()
```

and set everything inside the function in a extension, it worked I got no errors but it looks like a bad solution to me, I had to initialize all of them with a 'dummy' value because lazy var require being initialized right away so...

Is it a bad practise?
Is there any better way to accomplish that?

thank you in advance for the answers!

Comment: Why do they _need_ to be lazy?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a really good reason for not just storing these properties in the class itself.

So the way to work around it is to use objc_getAssociatedObject and objc_setAssociatedObject.

For example, in your extension you could put:

```
struct AssociatedKeys 
{
    static var infoButton: UInt8 = 0
}

private(set) var infoButton: UIButton? 
{
    get 
    {
        guard let value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.infoButton) as? UIButton else 
        {
            return nil
        }
        return value
    }
    set(newValue) 
    {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.infoButton, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }
}
```